# PowerShell remote event log clearing error: path to [computer] cannot be found

Tags: windows, powershell, event-log, powershell-remoting

I am running a script that collects and clears event logs for every machine on a network.
for some reason, when the script gets to the part where it needs to clear out the event logs for a workstation it throws an error saying "path to [computer] cannot be found".
This network switched from a standard setup of several physical workstations connected to a network managed with VMware. it has a mix of virtual servers/workstations along with physical engineering workstations.

the script I'm using worked without issue when it was a more standard setup with no virtual workstations/servers.

all the servers & workstation names are stored in an array and called into the function
"clear-eventlog -logname application, system, security -computername $var" with $var calling from the array of names.

I know the computers aren't misnamed in the array since it has no trouble pulling the audit logs from the workstations, and has no trouble clearing audit logs for the virtual servers.

It is only when it tries to clear the audit logs from the physical workstations that the error gets thrown, so i think it may be some sort of permission issue causing the audit logs to not be visible to the 'clear-eventlog' function but i have not been able to figure out how to get around it.

how do i get it to clear logs for the physical workstations?

```
#not exact, rewriting from memory
#skipping over most of the script, but this is the section thats throwing an error

@var = @(server1, server2, workstation1, workstation2, etc)

##issue with this part only when clearing physical workstation logs
clear-eventlog -LogName Application, Security, System, "Symantec Endpoint Protection Client" -computername $var

##error message
"path to [workstation name] cannot be found"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$computername = [computer1, computer2, etc]

for ($i=0; $i -lt $computername.length; $i++){

invoke-command -computerName $computername -scriptblock {clear-eventlog -logname application, security, system}

}
```

Comment: I've posted a new answer because I saw your post in the review thread and decided to add some info.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the error from the original question is `the network path was not found`. [Your post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74816168/761095) does not have an explanation of the error message, so I want to add a new answer.

You may see the error message `the network path was not found` when the computer specified in the `-ComputerName` is unreachable. You need to validate and verify if the computer name is correct and if the computer is actually reachable. I think that you may use a csv file to store the names of computers and validate if all of them are reachable before running `Clear-EventLog`, but that's another topic.

Besides the connectivity problem and the `network path was not found` error, the script in @baconbacon's answer won't work because the syntax is incorrect. And BTW there is no need for `Invoke-Command` and the `for` loop in this particular case.

1. This line needs to be replaced:

   `$computername = [computer1, computer2, ...]`

   with

   `$computername = @("computer1", "computer2")`

   I assume that you are passing an [array of strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays) to `Invoke-Command`, so you need to use the `@("foo", "bar")` syntax above.
2. You don't need to use `Invoke-Command` because the `Clear-EvenLog` supports remoting, and the `-ComputerName` parameter. So you may replace the following code:

   `invoke-command -computerName $computername -scriptblock {clear-eventlog -logname application, security, system}`

   With this one:

   `Clear-EventLog -LogName "LogFoo", "LogBar" -ComputerName $computername`
3. And you don't need to use the `for` or even `foreach` loop. The `-ComputerName` parameter accepts the array of strings, so you don't have to iterate through the `$computername` array.